# Prove that g=e for a finite group G

Tags: group-theory

Suppose G is a finite group of order n and m is relatively prime to n. If $g \in G$ and $g^{m}=e$, prove that $g=e$.

Let $\left | G \right |=n$ and $gcd\left ( n,m \right )=1$

> Recall:
>   $\left | g \right | \mid \left | G \right |$ for an element $g \in G$

This implies $\left | G \right |=k\left | g \right | \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$

How do I use the fact that gcd(n,m)=1 to aid me?

Looking only for **hints**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $\text{gcd}(m,n) = 1$, there exist integers $a,b$ such that $1 = am + bn$.

Comment: As suspected. I tried this and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $k=|g|$. Recall that $g^m=e$ if and only if $k\mid m$; if you’ve seen this before, it’s the key fact that you need, and you should try to prove it. You also know that $k\mid n$.

Comment: Bezout's identity works. But I will attempt the question using your hint.